# Was Count Dooku masking his true Sith nature (yellow eyes and decrepit look) with the Force?

Tags: star-wars, sith, revenge-of-the-sith

Some fans believe Palpatine was using Force enhancement to cover up his Sith disfigurements (due to decades of using the dark-side) and yellow eyes before his fight with Mace Windu.

Is it possible he taught Dooku to do the same? Or is it because Dooku was once a Jedi (and therefore not totally consumed by hate) that he does not look disfigured like other Sith?

Comment: This is actually a good question. It is generally said that one would be disfigured after *years* of immersion in the dark side, but Vader's eyes turned yellow almost immediately. I suppose it was a bit of both -- Dooku had to look normal for diplomacy, and his years as a Jedi probably helped.

Comment: @Null: I thought the issue was that one's eyes turned yellow after using large amounts of dark side power, rather than the length of time involved. Vader drew on a lot of power to destroy the separatists on Mustafar, while Palpatine used even more power in his combat with Windu, whereas Dooku relied more on his swordsmanship and Force abilities rather than raw power.

Comment: @JamesSheridan I think we are both correct -- it generally takes years for one's eyes to change to yellow, but heavy use of the dark side within a short period would accelerate the process and explain Vader's eyes changing so quickly.

Comment: I thought Palpatine wasn't actually disfigured - rather he was a member of a nonhuman race (the Sith) that had mastered the Dark Side of the Force. The yellow eyes and wrinkles were his natural appearance which he was disguising.

Comment: @RobertF - nope, Palpatine has been confirmed as Naboo, which are humans.

Comment: @RobertF: Omegacron is right, and while the Sith species were non-human, their appearance was fairly different to Palpatine's anyway.

Comment: @RobertF The Sith species was bright red and they were possiblely extinct (at least the pureblooded ones). http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_(species)

Answer (score 11):

I disagree with saying that Dooku was hiding his appearance, for the following reasons:

- **1) Despite of what most fans believe, the official state is that Palpatine wasn't always ugly:**

  A very discussed state, but it's clear:

  From [**Official Databank**](http://starwars.com/databank/emperor-palpatine-darth-sidious), and [**Wiki's discussion on Palpatine**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Palpatine/Archive_1) (see *Palpatine's appearance*)

  > Skywalker witnessed a stunning sight: the Chancellor, cornered, with Windu looming over him with his lightsaber blade extended. Palpatine unleashed a torrent of Sith lightning at the Jedi Master, but Windu was able to deflect it back at the Chancellor. The evil energies twisted Palpatine's face as they flowed through him, scarring and **disfiguring his once handsome features**. His eyes burned yellow, his voice grew ragged and deep, and he became a well of dark side energies.

  So, in this perspective there's no base to assume that Dooku would hide his appearance.
- **2) Not *every* Sith is ugly:**

  Although in the movies it seems that every Sith is scarfed, there are other sources, games for example, that presents young, pretty Sith, both Masters and apprentice... (In *KOTOR* for example, travel to the Sith academy and see)
- **3) Dooku kept his looks in Episode III**

  In the Anakin vs Dooku fight in Episode III, it had been some years since Dooku assumed his dark identity, and he had grown stronger.

  Since everybody knew he was a Sith, why would he keep hiding his *true* appearance? Shouldn't he unleash and embrace his dark side?